# is it possible to run minify html of page speed from the command line?

Tags: c++, pagespeed

is it possible to run minify html of page speed from the command line?
If so, how? 
i only want to compact my html file.i don't need other function of page speed.
so i want to extract this function of page speed.

Comment: i found this file "https://code.google.com/p/page-speed/source/browse/lib/trunk/src/pagespeed/apps/minify_html.cc?r=2382". but now my question is how to compile this file in windows

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to compile from source, the mod_pagespeed sources contains an example[1] of how to use the underlying PageSpeed Optimization SDK that will do that what you want with a small modification.

At the point where it passes in a url (test.com), you can add filters on the querystring like this:
"?ModPagespeedFilters=collapse_whitespace"

Then it will output the html file you send in to it with all whitespace collapsed.

[1] https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/source/browse/trunk/src/net/instaweb/automatic/static_rewriter_main.cc

Answer (score 0):

The htmlcompressor project is a Java program that you can run from the command line: https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/

If you have Python installed, django-htmlmin has a command-line mode (you don't need django installed to use this): https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-htmlmin (However, it seems to choke on files with non-ascii characters in it.)

If you are on Windows, this freeware tool supports a command line mode: http://www.alentum.com/ahc/